# Need to create a method with custom type

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I have a method as mentioned below :

```
protected Super<?> generateSuper(Serializable object) throws IOException   {
        Object data = getData(object);
        Super<Object> sup = new SuperImpl<Object>(data);
        return sup;
 }
```

On this line , I want to pass custom type. How can i do this?
For example : I want to create Super of any other class type.
Can I pass any argument to the method that can be passed at the place of byte[] in the method?

The class SuperImpl looks like :

```
public class SuperImpl<T> implements Super<T>{
    public SuperImpl(T data) {  
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a generic method:

```
protected <T> Super<T> generateSup(Serializable object) throws IOException {
    T data = getData(object); //questionable
    Super<T> sup = new SuperImpl<T>(data);
    return sup;
}
```

You will be able to call it like:

```
<byte[]>generateSup(object);
//or
<String>generateSup(anotherObject);
//or
<OtherClassType>generateSup(someOtherObject);
```

There's one thing you have to make sure, though.

You have to make sure that the `getData(object)` returns `T`. If you do, this method will compile. Otherwise, if the `getData(object)` *always* returns `Object`, you have to provide a constructor in the `SuperImpl` class that consumes a `Object`.